# VBA: REGEX LOOKBEHIND MS ACCESS 2010

Tags: regex, vba, lookbehind

I have a function that was written so that VBA can be used in MS Access
I wish to do the following

I have set up my code below. Everything before the product works perfectly but trying to get the information behind just returns "" which is strange as when i execute it within Notepad++ it works perfectly fine

So it looks for the letters MIP and one of the 3 letter codes (any of them)

```
 StringToCheck = "MADHUBESOMIPTDTLTRCOYORGLEJ"

' PART 1
' If MIP appears in the string, then delete any of the following codes if they exist - DOM, DOX, DDI, ECX, LOW, WPX, SDX, DD6, DES, BDX, CMX,
' WMX, TDX, TDT, BSA, EPA, EPP, ACP, ACA, ACE, ACS, GMB, MAL, USP, NWP.
' EXAMPLE 1.  Flagged as: MADHUBESOMIPTDTLTRCOYORGLEJ, should be MADHUBESOMIPLTRCOYORGLEJ


Do While regexp(StringToCheck, "MIP(DOM|DOX|DDI|ECX|LOW|WPX|SDX|DD6|DES|BDX|CMX|WMX|TDX|TDT|BSA|EPA|EPP|ACP|ACA|ACE|ACS|GMB|MAL|USP|NWP|BBX)", False) <> ""
    ' SELECT EVERYTHING BEFORE THE THREE LETTER CODES
     strPart1 = regexp(StringToCheck, ".*^[^_]+(?=DOM|DOX|DDI|ECX|LOW|WPX|SDX|DD6|DES|BDX|CMX|WMX|TDX|TDT|BSA|EPA|EPP|ACP|ACA|ACE|ACS|GMB|MAL|USP|NWP|BBX)", False)
    ' SELECT EVERYTHING AFTER THE THREE LETTER CODES
     strPart2 = regexp(StringToCheck, "(?<=(DOM|DOX|DDI|ECX|LOW|WPX|SDX|DD6|DES|BDX|CMX|WMX|TDX|TDT|BSA|EPA|EPP|ACP|ACA|ACE|ACS|GMB|MAL|USP|NWP|BBX).*", False)
StringToCheck = strPart1 & strPart2
Loop
```

The function i am using which i have taken from the internet is below

```
Function regexp(StringToCheck As Variant, PatternToUse As String, Optional CaseSensitive As Boolean = True) As String

On Error GoTo RefErr:

Dim re As New regexp
re.Pattern = PatternToUse
re.Global = False
re.IgnoreCase = Not CaseSensitive

Dim m
For Each m In re.Execute(StringToCheck)
    regexp = UCase(m.Value)
Next

RefErr:
    On Error Resume Next

End Function
```

Comment: The MS Scripting RE engine does not support look-behinds.

Comment: If "PART 1" is all you need to do you would be better of using instr to look for "MIP" then a 3-step-char-loop to remove the tokens (IMO this would be better even if lbh were available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in two steps:

1. Check if `MIP` is in the string
2. If it is, remove the other codes.

Like this:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim StringToCheck As String
  StringToCheck = "MADHUBESOMIPTDTLTRCOYORGLEJ"

  Debug.Print StringToCheck
  Debug.Print CleanupString(StringToCheck)
End Sub

Function CleanupString(str As String) As String
  Dim reCheck As New RegExp
  Dim reCodes As New RegExp

  reCheck.Pattern = "^(?:...)*?MIP"
  reCodes.Pattern = "^((?:...)*?)(?:DOM|DOX|DDI|ECX|LOW|WPX|SDX|DD6|DES|BDX|CMX|WMX|TDX|TDT|BSA|EPA|EPP|ACP|ACA|ACE|ACS|GMB|MAL|USP|NWP|BBX)"
  reCodes.Global = True

  If reCheck.Test(str) Then
    While reCodes.Test(str)
      str = reCodes.Replace(str, "$1")
    Wend
  End If

  CleanupString = str
End Function
```

Note that the purpose of `(?:...)*?` is to group the letters in threes.

---

Since the VBScript regular expression engine does support look-aheads, you can of course also do it in a single regex:

```
Function CleanupString(str As String) As String
  Dim reClean As New RegExp

  reClean.Pattern = "^(?=(?:...)*?MIP)((?:...)*?)(?:DOM|DOX|DDI|ECX|LOW|WPX|SDX|DD6|DES|BDX|CMX|WMX|TDX|TDT|BSA|EPA|EPP|ACP|ACA|ACE|ACS|GMB|MAL|USP|NWP|BBX)"

  While reClean.Test(str)
    str = reClean.Replace(str, "$1")
  Wend

  CleanupString = str
End Function
```

Personally, I like the two-step check/remove pattern better because it is a lot more obvious and therefore more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, This was exactly what i was looking for. I could have used the other non Reg-ex method but this is only the first part in a 6 part process which is why I'm marking it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Non RE option:

```
Function DeMIPString(StringToCheck As String) As String
    If Not InStr(StringToCheck, "MIP") Then
        DeMIPString = StringToCheck
    Else
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To Len(StringToCheck) Step 3
            Select Case Mid$(StringToCheck, i, 3)
                Case "MIP", "DOM", "DOX", "DDI", "ECX", "LOW", "WPX", "SDX", "DD6", "DES", "BDX", "CMX", "WMX", "TDX", "TDT", "BSA", "EPA", "EPP", "ACP", "ACA", "ACE", "ACS", "GMB", "MAL", "USP", "NWP":
                Case Else
                    DeMIPString = DeMIPString & Mid$(StringToCheck, i, 3)
            End Select
        Next
    End If
End Function
```